# Is it possible to peek at the next element in a range-for loop?

Tags: c++

Say I have this:

```
void test(std::vector<int>& my_ints) {
    for (auto& my_int : my_ints) {
        if (my_int == 5 && /* not the last value in the vector */) {
            my_int += /* next value in the vector */;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any valid syntax to replace the comments with?

PS! yes, i know, piece of cake with a regular for loop but I want to see if I can use range-for loops for this type of stuff.

Comment: You could create a thin wrapper for vector with an iterator that returns a pair of references instead of just one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to peek at the next element

In general case - no.

Since objects in `std::vector` are stored contiguously, you *could* do `*(&my_int + 1)`, but if you change the container later, the code might silently break. Don't do that!

---

And to check if the current element is the last one, you could use `&my_int == &my_ints.back()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a safe way to do what you want, with a ranged loop.

If you can bare an extra helper function, you could somehow generalize the algorithm you are using, though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <class Container, class BinaryOp>
void apply_using_the_next(Container& cc, BinaryOp op)
{
    if (std::cbegin(cc) == std::cend(cc))
        return;
    std::transform(std::begin(cc), std::prev(std::end(cc)),
                   std::next(std::cbegin(cc)),
                   std::begin(cc), op);
}

void test(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    apply_using_the_next(v, [] (const int a, const int b) {
        return a == 5 ? a + b : a;
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1};

    test(a);

    for (auto const i : a)       // ->  2 9 4 3 10 6 1
        std::cout << ' ' << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Live, [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/z0TzMpuKjXHmRgHj).

Answer (score -4):

You can use iterator.

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = my_ints.begin(); it < my_ints.end() - 1; ++it) {
    if (*it == 5 /* no need to check as iterating until second last value && it != my_ints.end() - 1*/) {
        *it += *(it+1);
    }
}
```

Even if the vector is empty, the loop won't enter as it < my_ints.end() - 1 will return false, so it is safe.

Comment: It is not safe: if vector is empty, `end() - 1` is undefined. Also, the question was "how to use range-based loop" for this task, not how to convert range-based loop into iterator loop.